# Pause OnBlur validation input form AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input, angular-ngmodel

The problem is that I send the form to the server and if the email is already in use, the message of the error "already in use" is shown fine, but if the user wants to click in "recover-password" link, he can't, because the "on blur" event of the input is fired and the message is hidden.
Can I pause the "on blur" event of the input after de server error response? How can I solve this?
**I want to keep the error visible until the user clicks the submit button again.**
AngularJS version is 1.4.9.
Thank you for the help. 
The code:

```
<form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" ng-submit="createUser($event)">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" 
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
        ng-model="register.email" required>
    <div ng-messages="registerForm.email.$error" ng-Show="registerForm.email.$dirty && registerForm.email.$invalid">
        <div class="form-error is-visible" ng-message="required">required</div>
        <div class="form-error is-visible" ng-message="alreadyTaken">Email already in use. <a href="/recover-password">Do you want to recover the password?</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: make changes after the response is back from the server, apply the logic in the controller. I would not suggest going for a delay or something like the answer given below suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `debounce` option for delay in update.

Try:

`ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur', debounce: { 'blur': 500 } }"` for a half second delay on blur